# How do I prepare for a medical examination?

Tags: work-environment

I recently got an invitation for a medical examination. This exam is mandated by national regulations concerning office health and safety, and is for all employees who perform a certain amount of computer monitor related work. It's my first medical examination connected to a job. The invitation mentions I'll be required to give an urine sample, which I understand is normal (although I personally think it's weird because I don't see what my urine has to do with computer monitor usage).

As I mentioned, it's my first medical examination since I graduated from high school and i'm not quite sure how to prepare or what to expect. Should I be careful with what I drink or eat that day to avoid skewing the urine sample results? I'm not a smoker, I don't drink alcohol or do drugs, so I don't think that'll be an issue.

Comment: As an aside, It was somewhat challenging to find an appropriate tag, since there's nothing about medical examinations or similar in the tags.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about requirements for a medical procedure and not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: @CMW It's borderline in my opinion. It's a medical procedure which is a consequence of workplace rules and as such is related to the workplace.

Comment: To me it's akin to asking 'How do I prepare to sue my boss over salary not paid?' which is asking for legal advice though work related. The procedure may be work related, but it's really a medical procedure, so a doctor should tell you how to prepare for it.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It is a company-wide invitation. Our company is an IT company, and as such we do a lot of work with computer monitors, often with 2 monitors at the same time. According to health and safety regulations on a national level, this means we need a regular preventative medical exam to ensure we don't run into issues.

Comment: This is lickly to be no more then a 5 minite eye test and asking you if you get and pain from sitting in the chair all day.

Comment: Is this required by your employer? Will your employer have access to your results? It sounds like it's more along the line of an extra benefit being offered ("your work environment might have adverse effects on your health, so here's a chance to get checked out to make sure you're ok"). Could you [edit] your question to clarify a bit?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs And what does a urine sample have to do with "computer work".

I am sure this q used to refer to a mandatory "drugs" test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prepare, it would make sense to ask your company some questions or read the information they probably provided for you before you take the exam.

You probably want to know exactly what tests will be administered, how long it will take, etc.

You probably want to know if the information gathered during the exam will be completely confidential (as it would be if you went to your own physician), or if any results will be shared with your company.

I also fail to see that there is any real connection between computer monitor usage and urine tests. You may have misunderstood the intent, or they are actually testing for far more than monitor-induced affects.

As far as what you should do physically, that depends completely on the tests being administered. Some tests require fasting, others do not, for example.

If you are worried that a drug screen will be performed (you mentioned "I don't drink alcohol or do drugs") and used against you, then you may want to fully read and understand the details of the testing and test reporting before you consent.

Personally, I keep my medical history and my company separate. I get regular checkups, have a regular physician, and don't need to have my company provide any exams. The only time when I allow company and medicine to intersect is when I get a company-provided flu shot. Everything else I keep at arms length. I want to be completely in control of my medical information, and I'm not confident that company-sponsored screenings and exams allow me that control. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

Relax, you don't need to do anything. I'd hope it goes without saying that if you do use any illegal substances then you should stop, but other than that you should continue as normal. Don't think of it as an examination in the pass / fail sense - it's merely a check up.

They're not there to catch you out (In fact, it sounds from the context that it's been done to fulfil employer obligations to you and not the other way round), so you should be honest with the doctor about any issues you have. If you don't have any, they'll more than likely do a number of non-invasive tests such as blood pressure, heart rate, reactions and maybe a hearing test.

The urine sample is probably to check for the presence of blood and protein which could indicate problems - again, nothing to worry about and very routine.

Comment: The only "substance" (if you can even call it that) that I use is a prescription drug to deal with my Asperger's. I don't know if it's relevant or not.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs You may choose to tell the doctor if he asks about medication, but you really don't have anything to worry about from what I can see.

Comment: they'll likely do an eyesight test as well

Comment: If you have a prescription for that drug, then even if its detected, the results can be explained.

Comment: Hope that the examining doctor lubricates his index finger.

Comment: the comment about "careful about eating and drinking" was more related to not unintentionally skewing the test results on the urine test by, for example, drinking coffee or soda or eating certain food before the test, since the exam is an hour after lunchtime.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Unless you ingest a ton of poppy seeds (which may or may not show up as opiates in a urine test...I haven't figured out the truth to this) there's really *nothing* that will skew a urine test as they test for specific things (such as drugs). If you are clean, there's nothing to worry about.